# How to use VI to search for lines less than a certain length?

Tags: vi

I know how to use VI to find lines longer than a certain number of characters:

```
/\%>80v.\+
```

But how do I search for lines **shorter** than a certain number of characters?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use

```
/^.\{,25}$/
```

to find lines shorter than 25 characters.

Comment: Great, if you appreciate the answer, you should up vote it and/or accept it. see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: This finds lines less than or equal to 25 characters in my copy of Vim.

Comment: A brief explanation on whats going on would be nice ! :)

Comment: \{n,m} matches from n to m of the preceding characters.

\{,m} matches at most m (from 0 to m) of the preceding characters.

. matches any character.

^ matches the beginning of a line.

$ matches the end of a line.

hence: match a line which contains from beginning to end up to m characters of any type.

Comment: Great answer! However I think the second curly brace should be escaped too: `/^\{,25\}$/`.

Comment: @cezar the second backslash is allowed but not required.

Comment: @BasBossink Thanks for the reply. I didn't know that. I always escape both curly braces, it is more intuitive and comprehensible in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this on a large file and had to kill -9 vim after it didn´t finish after a few minutes (!). I love vim but this disappointed me somewhat. I wonder if this is implemented as a trendy new python plug-in or something.
To find short lines in a more time-effective way I find that it is better to use

```
awk  '{ if(length<YOURLENGTH) { print $0 }}'
```